# I create a new xml file and set local copy but is not in my application folder

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0

I have a C# 4.0 application and in the root of my project I have created a xml file. I set it as local copy but when I compile the project the xml is not in the application folder.

Xml is an special type of file? because other types of files are copied without problems.

Thanks.

Comment: No they're not special; it should just work. You have `Build Action = Content` and `Copy to Output Directory = Copy Always` ?

Comment: In build action I had resource, I change to Content. Copy I had always. But the result is the same.

Comment: Is it really in the root of the project (also inside the solution)? Or in some subdirectory?

Comment: Now works, I exit and enter again in visual studio and setting build action as Content works.